# Oracle SQL: Return first line of string using regexp_substr

Tags: sql, regex, string, oracle, carriage-return

I am trying to return the first line of text from a text box in an SQL query (oracle 11).  The content of the text box looks like this:

```
   X WITHDRAWN

   Explanation.
```

I want to return the top line, i.e. the X WITHDRAWN.  I'm not sure if I can specify to look at the first line only, or to just return all text before a carriage return - either would work.

I think I need to use regexp_substr but I'm not quite sure on the syntax. I have tried:

```
   regexp_substr(TABLE.TEXT,'^.*$')
```

but it didn't work, so any assistance would be much appreciated!

EDIT:  The solution used:

```
   select regexp_substr(TABLE.TEXT, '[^,]+['||CHR(10)||']') from tab
```

EDIT: I noticed I was getting a mixture of line feed and carriage returns returned in my answer, so I've use the following solution to return just the text and no additional characters.

```
    select 
     replace(replace(regexp_substr(TABLE.TEXT, '[^,]+['||CHR(10)||']'),CHR(10),''),CHR(13),'') 
     from tab
```

EDIT:  Following @Ben's answer, I've amended my solution to the following:

```
select
initcap(replace(regexp_substr(TABLE.TEXT, '.*$', 1, 1, 'm'),CHR(13),''))
from tab
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Parado's regular expression matches everything that's not a comma multiple times followed by a carriage return. This means it won't work for a line-feed or if there's a comma in the text.

Oracle supports multi-line expressions using the `m` [match parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions147.htm#CIHDAIHJ). When using this mode, `$` matches the end of each line as well as the end of the string. You can use this to simply the expression massively to:

```
regexp_substr(str, '.*$', 1, 1, 'm')
```

That is match the first occurrence (the first line) of the string that matches anything, followed by the end of the string, counting from the first character.

As an example:

```
with strings as ( 
 select 'hi
         hi again' as str
   from dual
  union all
 select 'bye
         and again'
   from dual
        )
 select regexp_substr(str, '.*$', 1, 1, 'm')
   from strings
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Ben, although @Parado's worked for my purposes, I think this is the best answer as I only need to remove character 13, rather than that and character 10.

Answer (score 2):

You may try using direct substring (with carriage return - Chr(10) - being symbol to find) instead of regular expressions:

```
  SubStr(Table.Text, 1, decode(InStr(Table.Text, Chr(10)), 0, Length(Table.Text), InStr(Table.Text, Chr(10))) - 1)
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to do the trick, but I've accepted @Parado's as the answer just because it's a bit simpler!