# How to get first line of a string in oracle query?

Tags: oracle

Expiry Date:

```
15/05/12-15/07/12

minimum 15 May 2012 maximum 15 July 2012, the exact period in Charterers option
```

above is the cell value in a column and I need to show the only first line of the value i.e. 15/05/12-15/07/12

```
To_Char(b.Charter_End_Date, 'DD/MM/RR') || Period_Notice "Expiry Date",
```

expected result:

```
15/05/12-15/07/12
```

actual result:

```
15/05/12-15/07/12

minimum 15 May 2012 maximum 15 July 2012, the exact period in Charterers option
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle SQL: Return first line of string using regexp\_substr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17652730/oracle-sql-return-first-line-of-string-using-regexp-substr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substring, up to `CHR(10)`, might be what you're looking for:

```
SQL> select * From test;

COL
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
15/05/12-15/07/12

minimum 15 May 2012 maximum 15 July 2012, the exact period in Charterers option


SQL> select substr(col, 1, instr(col, chr(10))) result
  2  from test;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
15/05/12-15/07/12

SQL>
```